# How to assign an operation like sum or substitute, etc., to a variable

Tags: python

I want to do something like

```
class A:
    def __init__( self, left, right, op ):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.op = op
    def calculate( self ):
        self.number = op( self.left, self.right )
        return self.number
```

and use it, for example, like this:

```
a = A( 1, 2, + )
a2 = A( 2, 3, * )
```

I tried to do

```
op = +
op = __add__
```

but none of these worked. Can somebody tell is this possible (and if it is, how this is called, because I don't even know how to search it). Or the only possible way is to have a big, ugly `if-else` statement in `calculate` and check the value of `op`, which will be stored as `str`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to supply a lambda function as the third parameter:

```
a = A( 1, 2, lambda x,y: x + y)
b = A( 1, 2, lambda x,y: x * y)
```

This would allow you to support more complex operations, not present in the `operator` module.

Answer (score 9):

See the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module.

```
a = A( 1, 2, operator.add )
```