# Module `operator` in python has no `rfloordiv`?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Suppose I have s class, that has members `op`, `left`, `right` (this is related question to [How to assign an operation like sum or substitute, etc., to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769696/how-to-assign-an-operation-like-sum-or-substitute-etc-to-a-variable) ). So, in `op` I store an operator, for example - `operator.add`, `operator.radd`, etc. But I want to store `operator.rfloordiv` and there's no such member in this class? :\ But I **can** overload `__rfloordiv__`, so it **does** exist at all.

The idea is to apply `op` to `left` and `right` when needed.

My approach is as follows: store some special string in my `op` and then, before applying `op`, to check if `op` is string. If so, write an ugly `if-else` statement, to check for all - `rfloordiv`, `rmod`, `rtruediv`. If not - just apply `op` with both parameters. But this is damn ugly..

Is there a better way to achieve this?

I know that this could be done with `lambda` function, but if I do it like this, is there any way to see what is this `lambda` function (for the moment, when I need to see what is `op`, I check it in an `if` statement like this: `if self.op is operator.radd: ..`, but what if `op` is `lambda` function ? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most magic operator methods come in two flavours: the plain variant and the variant prefixed with `r` (example `__add__()` and [`__radd()__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)).  If you try to add the objects `a` of type `A` and `b` of type `B`, Python first calls `A.__add__(a, b)`.  If this returns the special value `NotImplemented`, `B.__radd__(b, a)` is called.

Both those magic methods corresond to `operator.add` in the `operator` module.  Similarly, the magic methods `__floordiv__()` and `__rfloordiv__()` correspond to `operator.floordiv`.